# Which fields are being searched by Facebook graph search?

Tags: facebook

Facebook docs are quite sparse on this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, see "Searching".

It is possible to search against several object types, but it is not clear which specific object attributes / fields / columns (whatever you call them) are being searched.

Which specific attributes / fields are being searched for each object type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience with search api.

- type=pages searches index of name and description
- type=group searches index of name
- type=event searches index of name and description
- type=user searches index of name
- type=post searches index of message

There maybe more included, these are just from my observation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fields extractable with:

graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=TYPE&fields=FIELDS&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

are depending on the object you want to search. They are those you can see if you request:

https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID

If I search

graph.facebook.com/search?q=troy&type=page&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I will obtain for example the object with ID "114198018660591", so I can only search for these fields:

"id": "114198018660591",
   "name": "Troy",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/195743_114198018660591_3661508_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Troy/114198018660591",
   "likes": 2418231,
   "category": "Movie",
   "can_post": true,
   "talking_about_count": 17956

obtained with (https://graph.facebook.com/114198018660591).

Therefore I can do a research like:

graph.facebook.com/search?q=troy&type=page&fields=id,name,category&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

but NOT like:

graph.facebook.com/search?q=troy&type=page&fields=id,name,category,website&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

also if the field "website" is recorded in some object data.

Answer (score 0):

type=group currently returns an empty data array since May.